# copy images from one folder to another based on column in csv

Tags: r

I have a folder with thousands of wildlife images. Most have been analyzed but there are several that I would like to pull out to be analyzed further. I have a csv that has a line for each image and a column indicating whether the image is "done" or needs a "redo." I would like to copy all images that need a "redo" from the larger folder and put them in another folder.

I have used code that removes them from the original folder and renames them but I would like them to be copied and keep the dame information sot the exif data remains the same.

This is the R code I have tried:

```
# read the CSV file into R
file_names <- read.csv("redo.csv", header = FALSE)[, 1]

# specify the path of the new directory
new_directory <- "E:/OWW/vollunteer pics/2018/redo"

# loop through the file names and move each file to the new directory
for (i in 1:length(file_names)) {
  file.rename(file_names[i], paste0(new_directory, file_names[i]))}
```

I would like the images to maintain there exif data and to only be copied from he original folder.

Comment: You do not have to read the images. Just copy the files use `file.copy` to copy the files to the desired location